# How to deal with unsupported (abandoned) WordPress plug-ins?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've been working with Drupal on the company I work for building large enterprise solutions and its community has shown mature enough so we can find ourselves confident and secure to build upon this platform and also contribute back with bug fixing, enhancements, support and so on.

Recently we decided to try WordPress as a platform for a specific type of website, mainly blogs, however we are starting to be concerned with the support provided by the plug-ins maintainers.

Within Drupal community, for instance, there is a policy for that, which entitles this topic. It addresses many of our concerns that raise when the maintainers are not releasing for a long time or even not responding on issue queues or anything at all. Please take a look here: https://www.drupal.org/node/251466

I haven't found something similar on WP community and I'd like to know how we could approach on this subject. We have a few contributions to give back and we have tried hard to contact a few developers, create forum topics, etc, with no response at all!

Please someone here help me out. I really wouldn't want to tell my managers the community/platform is not mature enough for enterprise solutions which demand a higher level of support.

If there's something I could help you with just tell me, I'm glad to start a discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically, there's nothing you can do about it!  If a developer decides they're done supporting their plugin, then well, they're done!

What YOU can do is use a little bit of research when selecting a plugin to use.  Look for plugins that have:

- large numbers of downloads
- issues that are responded to and closed in a timely manner
- recent updates

You can find all of this info in the Wordpress Plugin Repository.

Comment: You say that it is what it is because there is no such policy for this situation as the Drupal community which I consider a much more mature one has. The plug-ins I was referring to on my question above are largely used but apparently the maintainers decide by themselves when to look at the issues and release. I suppose an option here is to create a new plug-in based on the current one and start supporting from that. This is a common approach on open-source when a project is dead and someones forks and continues its development.